# How to display a local Excel spreadsheet with ngx-doc-viewer

Tags: excel, angular

I am trying to display an excel file that resides on the webserver using ngx-doc-viewer. I cannot find any examples of how to do this. It's a mystery.

I tried this:

```
<div class="viewer_container">
      <ngx-doc-viewer [url]="https://example.com/Docs/voucher.xlsx" viewer="office" style="width:100%;height:1200px;"></ngx-doc-viewer>
```

I'm guessing the viewer="office" refers to 365 or some online repository and not a local file?

Answer (score 0):

Office refers to the type of doc, like word. You can try google as well for a larger set of document view types. The docs need to be publicly accessible.